# Handling Mongoose connection failure in NestJS

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I am new to NestJS.

I am trying to connect to mongo instance, like this `MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/demo')`

How can I handle no connection here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you wrote wrong database URL.
You have to follow official documentation:
[Mongo](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb)